# ArcMap - maplex labels not displaying correctly with abbreviation dictionary

Tags: arcmap, labeling, maplex

I am using an abbreviation table to label the countries of the world.  I have double checked that the correct field is being used to label the map and that attributes in the field match the keyword in the abbreviation table.  I have also changed the label placement properties with the following settings checked:

- stacked label
- reduce font size
- abbreviate label, (with the following strategy order from top
  to bottom: stack label, abbreviate label, reduce label in size,
  compress label in width, overrun feature)

I also have remove duplicates, label largest feature part, and never remove (place overlapping) check as well.  The rest of the settings are the defaults, including the options of those settings that applies to (except the abbreviate label options of course where the abbreviation dictionary file is defined).

For some reason, some of the abbreviations are not displaying correctly.  For example, in the abbreviation dictionary I have North Korea abbreviated as N. Kor. however only the N. is being displayed on the map.  Same is happening with South Korea.  Sri Lanka is only showing Sri on the map when the abbreviation is set to be Sri Lan.

I've tried playing around with the strategy order and the rest of the settings, but nothing seems to display the abbreviation in the dictionary.

Does anyone know why this is happening and what I may have to change to get the labels in the abbreviation dictionary to display correctly?  I cannot attach images because the system I am working on with Arc is not connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Hornbydd.  Your response actually triggered something after I went to the page you referenced. Putting those countries that aren't displaying correctly in double quotations in the abbreviation column in the dictionary now displays the entire name if it fits and then the correct abbreviation when there's not enough space.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used an abbreviation dictionary before but read the help file there seems to be several [types of abbreviation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-text/abbreviating-and-truncating-about.htm#GUID-689991A1-F497-4012-839A-113D41F568E2). Taking your North Korea example that seems to be a simultaneously a *Keyword* and *Ending* style abbreviation. Maybe Maplex is unable to do that?